# Legal Question before going live

Tags: payments, xdr, compliance

As I'm getting closer to have a product (timed payments) 
which I would like to activate on the Stellar public net, I'm wondering 
which legal aspects I have to consider.

The setup for the current services is:
- The software does not hold any assets or values of the clients at any time
- Secret keys are only stored at the browser session, never on server side
- The service is free of charge
- The service provides submission of XDR-Envelopes. So worst case could be
that the submission of an XDR is not happening as promised. This could mean 
some problems/inconfiniences for the users, if they count on it.

My idea is to provide the service under the Apache-2.0 license. Provided free of charge and on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND. (https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)

Should I be safe then? Looking forward to hear your opinion.
PS: if that matters I'm based in Germany